# getting same result without using "limit" (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

How do i get the same result but without using "limit" in mysql?

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user_interest
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id)
ORDER BY (COUNT(user_id)) DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: This query does not really make sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Select top (2) ... ?

Comment: @GMB I am trying to get the most frequent number of user_id in user_interest

Comment: @CeliusStingher the function TOP doesn't work in mySQL 8.0.15

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some suggestion if you don't want to use limit

```
select t2.user_id 
from (
    select row_number() over (order by t1.ct desc) as rn, t1.userid 
    from (
        SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) as ct
        FROM user_interest
        GROUP BY user_id
        HAVING COUNT(user_id)
    )t1 
) as t2 where t2.rn < 3
```